# Is it possible to get a foreign marriage certificate authenticated by the US federal government? What are the available procedures?

Tags: paperwork

My marriage certificate was issued in Mongolia. Is there a way for me to get it authenticated (not apostilled) at the US federal level, either by the Department of State or another body such as the US consulate in Mongolia? If so, how can I apply for such authentication?

Comment: The government that is in a position to authenticate a document is the government that issued the document.  If you need a Mongolian document to be authenticated, you should approach the government of Mongolia.  Also, US consulates are part of the Department of State.

Comment: @phoog I see. I was advised by the Taiwan consular office to get my Mongolian marriage license authenticated by the US consulate in Mongolia. When I asked for alternatives, they said any US federal authentication is acceptable. Perhaps they were misinformed, or "authentication" was the wrong term.

Comment: If any kind of "authentication" suffices, then you could have your document notarized by a U.S. notary public and have the state department authenticate the notary's signature.

Answer (score 2):

Mongolia and the US are both parties to the Hague Apostille Convention. Therefore, a Mongolian document, with an apostille issued by some official recognized by Mongolia to issue apostilles, should be recognized for US purposes without needing any additional authentication by US officials.

US consular officials abroad are able to authenticate foreign documents issued in countries that are not party to the Hague Apostille Convention for use in the US. (See [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/records-and-authentications/authenticate-your-document/Notarial-Authentication-Services-Consular.html) and [7 FAM 870](https://fam.state.gov/fam/07fam/07fam0870.html).) But they will generally not provide authentication for documents issued in countries that are party to the convention.

In a comment to the question you mentioned something about Taiwan consular office. Do you wish to use this document in Taiwan? If so, the Taipei Trade and Economic Representative Office in Ulaanbaatar seems to have a page on authentication services (page in [Chinese](https://www.roc-taiwan.org/mn/cat/18.html) or [Mongolian](https://www.roc-taiwan.org/mn_en/cat/18.html)).

Comment: A response to my comment indicates that the document is required for some purpose in Taiwan and that authentication was requested by a Taiwanese official.  Does that change the answer? (I suppose not, and that the Taiwanese official was mistaken or confused, but perhaps you know of some circumstance in which this would make sense.)

Comment: @phoog: I updated with some info for Taiwan

Comment: @user102008 I will use the document at a Taiwan representative office in the US, and was directed by them to request authentication from TTERO in Ulaanbaatar. Surprisingly, TTERO denied my request saying that they only authenticate documents for Taiwanese citizens, and directed me to the US consulate. The Taiwan representative office in the US then clarified that any federal-level authentication could be accepted.